# Promise chaining error in Mocha

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, protractor, mocha.js

Getting error while trying to type the text using sendkeys or clicking button in the pop up with typescript promise chaining in Mocha.

```
composeNewMessage(mailCount: number, recepientsName: any, subject: string, messageContent: string,
  recipientLink?: ElementFinder, ccName?: any, bccName?: any,
  ccRecipientLink?: ElementFinder, bccRecipientLink?: ElementFinder): promise.Promise<void> {
  return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.listView.composeMsgBtn), 60000, 'Compose button to be clickable')
      .then(() => this.composeMsgBtn.click())
      .then(() => this.toButton.click())
      .then(() => util.log('To button clicked'))
      .then(() => recipientLink.click())
      .then(() => browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(this.loadingBar), 30000, 'Loading bar to be invisible'))
      .then(() => this.searchNameInput.sendKeys(recepientsName))
      .then(() => util.log('Search'))
      .then(() => this.contactList.contacts.get(0).click())
      .then(() => browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.contactList.saveButton), 30000, 'Save button to be clickable'))
      .then(() => this.contactList.saveButton.click());
}

describe('Logging in', () => {
it('should', (done: MochaDone) => {
      login
        .login(user, name, USER_PASSWORD)
        .then(() => util.log('Logged in.'))
        .then(() => nav.navigate('sat'))
        .then(() => util.log('Navigated to sat.'))
        .then(() => browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true))
        .then(() => composeView.composeNewMessage(3, [predefinedStudent1, predefinedStudent2], 'Test sub', MSG_CONTENT, contactList.studentLinkInRecipients))
        .then(() => composeView.listView.composeMsgBtn.click())
        .then(() => done())
        .catch((err) => done(err));
  });
});
```

"To button clicked" is getting printed in the console window. But after that getting the error as shown in the image below.
[Mocha error in promise chaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ZQ3.png)

Comment: Have you tried using .finally method after the last then clause  ?

Comment: You need to pass in done as a parameter and ensure it's called after the async operation is complete. 

If you're not sure how to do this, please paste your full code precisely the complete test case so we can help you.

Comment: Updated full code. This is a page object method called from a spec.

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of the error messages/code

Comment: This can't be all the code. I don't see a test case here. If you want help, really post all of your code, for real. Ideally, reproduce it with the smallest amount of code possible, and then post all of that. There's a good chance you will solve it yourself while narrowing it down like that. One strategy would be to comment out code until you stop getting the error. If you still get the error with barely any code, great! That will make it easier for us to help you figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Increase the test's timeout

It seems you expect to wait more than the set timeout (120000ms) and therefore you should set the timeout to a longer time.

Read how to do it [here: Mocha Timeouts](https://mochajs.org/#test-level)

### Analysis

According to the image your timeout is set to 120000ms (2 seconds)

Now, I don't now how `browser.wait` works. But according to the code it seems you expect to be waiting more than 120000ms:

1. before calling composeNewMessage, you wait for angular `browser.waitForAngularEnabled`
2. then there's the first `browser.wait` with **60000ms**
3. `browser.wait` again after logging "To button clicked" for **30000ms**
4. and `browser.wait` again for another **30000ms**

Now the reason you don't get "search" logged is probably due to long waiting before even calling composeNewMessage.

Comment: Thank you for the link : Mocha Timeouts. It fixed the issue.